# Como atualizar um componente de outra classe em React?

Tags: react

sou novo aqui no forum e estou estudando react e me deparei com uma dúvida..

Eu tenho os seguinte arquivos:

App.js

```
    class App extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            historico:[],
            isLoading: false
          }
          this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
      }

      loadData() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        functions.loadHistorico()
          .then((res)=>{
            this.setState({historico: res}),
            console.log(this.state.historico)
          })
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <li className="dropdown">
                <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Histórico <span className="caret"></span> </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu"> 
                  {this.state.historico.map(this.renderHistorico)}
                </ul>
              </li>
           )
      }


    }
```

e Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
      //>>> aqui tem o constructor(props) {}  e componentDidMount() {} etc...

      pesquisarTermo() {
        functions.salvarHistorico(this.refs.termo.value)
        //app.loadData()  <=====
      }
 }
```

Estou criando uma lista de um dropdown usando o map, porém quero atualizar esta lista toda vez que eu chamar a função pesquisarTermo() em Home.js.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Mas o `Home` é um componente filho de `App` ? Não o vejo no `render`.

Comment: Coloque o código do seu componente Home inteiro, se não da pra saber qual componente é filho, qual é pai.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve referenciar a classe filha App dentro do render da classe Pai.

```
import App from ../../App

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        <App/>
    }
}
```

Depois disso, tem um exemplo aqui de como chamar o método:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent